# Integration with PHP.js Javascript library

Tags: php, javascript, frameworks, phpjs

I am attempting to integrate the PHPJS (http://phpjs.org/) library with some code and am having trouble calling any of the functions and the library's websites does not have a step-by-step for getting started.

I am using the base download **php.default.min.js** and have created a bare bones page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="php.default.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert(phpversion());
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

I would expect that to produce a JavaScript alert but I only get a JS error of:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: phpversion is not defined.
```

How do I go about utilizing the functions in the PHP.js library?

Comment: Most likely, `php.default.min.js` is not getting loaded. Are you sure it's there on that path? ... That said, I'm not sure I get the point of using phpjs in the first place, but that's a different discussion and I'm sure it's been had before :)

Comment: I thought this might be the case, which is the reason I tried phpversion() first. The source seems to be linked (I can click on it when viewing the page's source in Chrome) but I cannot execute any functions contained within the library. Is there some other way of determining if the library loaded properly?

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint in the php js file in your Chrome Developer Tools. That should tell you whether it's loading correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're using the [default package](http://phpjs.org/packages/view/308), which doesn't come with the *phpversion* function. Try using the [full package](http://phpjs.org/packages/view/3775). Both releases have a list of supported functions in the links I've attached.

Hope it helps!

Comment: both links are dead :-(

Comment: please provide info how to use it and how to download php.default.min.js